# ASP.NET MVC2 Guid persistance issue

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 application on .NET 4.0 and built using VS 2010 that has two tables (amongst others), an `employees` table which has the following columns:
Firstname, MiddleName, LastName, NationalID, EmployeeType, MobileNumber, Email and UserId.

The `userId` field is a foreign key from the `aspnet_users` table which happens to be a guid. I am trying to persist the employee details for a selected user but cannot do so as I am getting an error.

The guid value for the selected user can be extracted and displayed using the ViewData dictionary. The `userId` guid value is `23aa8cd9-7552-403c-8c99-fcdd611cb188`.

I would like to persist this value together with other employee properties but when I submit the form I get the error shown below.
I am also using EF4 for my model. Here's the stacktrace:

```
System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
       at TechDispatch.Models.EmployeeRepository.SaveChanges() in C:\Projects\TechDispatch\TechDispatch\Models\EmployeeRepository.cs:line 131
       at TechDispatch.Models.EmployeeRepository.AddNewEmployee(Employee Add) in C:\Projects\TechDispatch\TechDispatch\Models\EmployeeRepository.cs:line 127
       at TechDispatch.Controllers.EmployeeController.Create(Employee employee) in C:\Projects\TechDispatch\TechDispatch\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:line 69
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       Message=String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=1
       Number=8152
       Procedure=""
       Server=.
       State=13
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       InnerException:
```

Could anyone please assist?

Comment: This error most likely has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC. Rather it's entity framework / SQL related. I propse you change the tags of your question to attract readers with knowledge about those fields. What database are you using anyway? You don't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this message means that you are adding a string that is too long for one of your char/varchar fields:

```
    String or binary data would be truncated.
    The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: In asmuch as I can agreee with you there I don't think I am supplying anything that is larger than what I set out all my varchar fields to be. I also have validation so I would know before posting. How about this message :Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues

Comment: Not sure what that line means.  If you're running on your local machine or on a machine that you have SA access to, you should be able to run SQL Profiler to see the exact query that is raising the error.

Comment: @imdondo: well say whatever you want but you have a field length or field type problem there. You are trying to store something in a column which does not fit the contents. It could the ID (it should be uniqueidentifier in SQL and Guid in your class) or something else. It could be that you have whitespace somewhere and you missed to see it.

Comment: @imdondo - If your guid field had a problem, you would get "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."  The error you're seeing is not related to your uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Sorrry Guys I think I have just realised that the Guid value I am dealing with seems to be the source of the problem. Just check the guid value I am try to insert here: 23aa8cd9-7552-403c-8c99-fcdd611cb188.This is not a 16 btye uniqueidentifier by any means is it? This has 32 characters- at least! Has anyone had such a problem before?

Comment: ... 32 hex digits = 16 bytes =)  Ignore the dashes and any curly braces.

Comment: Sorry Again but I have just moved the userId and UserName data from the aspnet_users table to another table with same definition on a different database using SSIS without any hitches. I guess I have to recreate the employees table just to be sure.

Comment: Regarding the database in use its SQL 2K8 R2 and EF4.